# JavaScript: ¿Como hago para hacer una operacion con porcentajes?

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer un programa que calcule la propina de un pago, y no se como hacer para usar el porcentaje

Por ejemplo, tengo $30 dolares y quiero sacar el 15% para sumarlo como propina, entonces probe esto:

```
alert(30*15%);
```

Pero no funciono, me dice que el "%" no es valido ¿Como hago para usar el porcentaje?

Saludos

Comment: Se que la pregunta ya está respondida. Pero quiero mencionar que Javascript no es una calculadora, es un lenguaje de programación y el signo `%` no sirve para eso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es suficiente con hacer en:

```
alert(30*1.15);
```

Donde el 15 sería el porcentaje.
Podrías probar cosas así incluso para estar tranquilo:

```
alert(100*1.99);
```

Eso devolvería 199.

Si lo que deseas es sacar el valor del porcentaje sobre el número.
Ejemplo el 10% de 30 sería 3.

En ese caso puedes hacer algo como:

```
alert(30*10/100);
```

Comment: Gracias! Funciono muy bien, nunca habia usado porcentajes por eso :D

Comment: De nada, agregué también a la respuesta como podrías sacar el valor del porcentaje de un número por si quieres ponerlo a parte, ej: el 10% de 30 devolvería 3. Favor marcar la respuesta como solución dándole al visto al costado de la respuesta si consideras que soluciona tu duda. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si ya lo hice, tarde porque stack overflow no me dejaba hasta que pasaran 10 minutos

Comment: Muchas gracias!